# Will WebBrowser generate an error if this happens

Tags: c#, winforms

IF a WebBrowser control is doing a Navigate() command, and before it finished I call another navigate command, does this cause on error does it simply start a new navigation and dump the old one?

Thanks!

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: He starts a new navigation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first Navigate command will simply be dumped. Naturally, it may however cause problems if you have event handlers following the initial Navigate that are still executing, expecting the page from the first Navigate.

Answer (score 1):

It simply start a new navigation and dump the old one.

Answer (score 0):

I won't produce any exceptions as long as you are not depending on custom code executed on the Navigating or ProgressChanged event handlers. The WebBrowser just cancels the current navigation and starts a new one.